# Custom date range query for ingesting data to data studio from big query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, looker-studio, sql-date-functions

I'm trying to create a GCP billing report for my org by fetching data from bigquery to data studio. Pretty new to sql programming in general, I've used the following query to visualize data in data studio.

```
SELECT
  project.name AS project,
  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM usage_start_time) AS month,
  ROUND(SUM(cost), 2) AS costs,
  ROUND(SUM((SELECT SUM(amount) FROM UNNEST(credits))), 2) AS credits
FROM `bqutil.billing.billing_dashboard_export`
GROUP BY project, month
ORDER by project, month
```

Now, i would like to add custom date range so that viewers can use it to get required report. However, the default custom range provided in in DS does not work. I'm from system admin background pretty new to bigquery and sql in general. Any help with the query would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: "the default custom range provided in in DS does not work" - why does is not work? what range are you expecting to get?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more, why it doesn't work ? Have you checked [this documentation's topic](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9272806?hl=en) about setting up a Date Range in Data Studio?

Comment: For example, i've changed the datasource for this report here https://datastudio.google.com/u/0/reporting/1MJ0GHVvcHI6cRHwMKyeSK3r7UoabEHOH/page/7yvW

and when i try changing the dates, it is applicable to pie chart and the graph but not the table. Please help. Pretty new to data studio and big query.

Comment: In the "Cost by Project" page, I changed the date filter to a few different ranges and every time all the views (the table, the graph and the pie chart) were updated and had consistent data. Can you help us by replication your problem in a way we can follow through?

Answer (score 1):

I have performed some tests and I found out the reason why, you are not being able to filter your data by date.

Since the dataset you are using is public I was able to use it to perform what you aim. I will describe my steps to achieve it:

1. Go to Data **Studio** >**Create**(upper left in the console)>**Data source**
2. Click on **BigQuery**
3. Click **Custom query**(left side of the window)
4. Type your query inside the query editor under *Enter custom query*(on the right side of the window)
5. On the upper right side of the screen click **Connect**
6. Click on **FIELDS** and check if all the fields have the appropriate type. Please double check the date field, it must be with date format
7. Create a table with the desired fields. In my case, I used two tables with the following characteristics:

> **Table 1:**
>
> *Data source:* BigQuery
>
> ***Date range dimension:month*** - Please DO NOT forget this field
>
> *Dimensions:* project, credits and month
>
> *Metric:* SUM(costs)
>
> *1st sort:* month
>
> *2nd sort:* costs

And another table:

> Table 2: heat map
>
> Data source: BigQuery
>
> ***Date range dimension:month*** - Please DO NOT forget this field
>
> *Dimensions:* project
>
> *Metric:* COUNT(project), AVG(cost), MIN(cost), MAX(cost)
>
> *1st sort:* cost

8. After configuring the table as described above, click at Date range filter in the tool bar (above the canvas). Drop it at your canvas
9. Now change the dates accordingly, the values should change

I found out that the dates filter do no work when ***Date range dimension*** is not set to you data field in the tables you want to filter by date.

Furthermore, I have also used the following query to test the date range filter. Below is the query:

```
SELECT
project.name AS project,
cast(FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%d" , usage_start_time) as date) AS start_date,
ROUND(SUM(cost), 2) AS costs,
ROUND(SUM((SELECT SUM(amount) FROM UNNEST(credits))), 2) AS credits
FROM `bqutil.billing.billing_dashboard_export`
GROUP BY project, start_date
ORDER by project, start_date
```

Notice that I just changed the **month** field to **start_date** as YYYYMMDD.